# Extract ID value from ASP.NET MVC Route URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, mono

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC application running on Mono. I currently have a controller like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("entity/{id}")]
public class EntityController {

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("doSomething")]
    public ActionResult DoSomething () {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I've overridden the following method of the controller:

```
protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
```

and in the body am trying to extract the {id} field so that I can set things up. At the moment, I'm having difficulty being able to reliably extract the value. The closest thing I saw that I tried was:

```
requestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]
```

But I haven't gotten this to work, usually returns null. Note that the reason I'm not doing something like

```
public ActionResult DoSomething (int id)
```

Is because this is prevented by a bug in Mono.

I would appreciate any help anyone can offer; I'm not yet willing to go down the road of regex'ing the full URL...

Thanks!

-- EDIT --

I've just found that calling this:

```
RouteData.Values ["id"];
```

Works when done from within the handling method itself, just not during Initilize(). Does anyone know how I can access this information reliably during Initilize()?

Comment: With your edit, have you tried `requestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]` inside the `Initialize` method?

Comment: Hi there. Yes this is what I originally attempted, but this returns null. The Values[] object is populated, but with a lot of random stuff that isn't useful for extracting the value.